# Error retrieving dependency Microsoft_VC100_CRT_X86

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I'm trying to create an installer with Visual Studio 2012 Premium and InstallShield LE 2015.

When I try to create the installer I get this error:

> error : -4072: Error retrieving dependency
>   Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.F1DD796A_B984_3DCA_A68D_6B352BDC86F3:0 of
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge
>   Modules\Cognex.Cnx.Core.Components 3.9.0.msm Merging
>   Cognex.Cnx.Core.Components 3.9.0: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Merge Modules\Cognex.Cnx.Core.Components 3.9.0.msm

How can I fix this problem? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and there is a reference to VC100. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that the merge module identified (note: at least the GUID is not likely to be part of the filename) as

> Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.F1DD796A_B984_3DCA_A68D_6B352BDC86F3:0

is a dependency of the Cognex merge module, but cannot be found in your merge module search paths. This could be due to bad search paths, or it could be due to not having the correct merge module. By its name, I would expect this merge module comes from Visual Studio 2010; is that installed on the machine on which you are building? If not, perhaps you can copy it from another machine that has it. If so, make sure that the directory it resides in is part of your merge module search path.